# Uploadify cancel individual file problem

Tags: php, jquery, uploadify

I have implemented uploadify in to my web application and it all works brilliantly except one thing. When the files are displayed in the queue, when I go to remove one from the queue I get an error.

The error is:

illegal character
jQuery(\'#'+a(this).attr(

and the code which this refers to is this:

```
<a href="javascript:jQuery(\'#'+a(this).attr("id")+"').uploadifyCancel('"+i+'\')">
```

If you could advise me that would be great. Thanks.

Comment: You need to escape the `"` like so: `\"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was the working code, he just modified it wrong.

```
<a href="javascript:$('#file_upload').uploadifyCancel($('.uploadifyQueueItem').eq(i).attr('id').replace('file_upload',''))">
```

The i variable defines which upload in the queue to cancel i.e. 0 is first, 1 second, -1 is last, -2 second last etc.. Alernatively if you have already grabbed the upload ID from uploadify, you can just do..

```
<a href="javascript:$('#file_upload').uploadifyCancel(ID)">
```

For reference in case anyone ends up here
http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/methods/uploadifycancel/

Also see http://api.jquery.com/eq/

Answer (score 1):

I think you are getting the quotes mixed up and escaped wrong. Try this:

```
<a href="javascript:jQuery('#'+a(this).attr('id')).uploadifyCancel(i)">
```

Comment: Its not my code - I downloaded it from Uploadify. This did not work :(

Comment: I have downloaded it again from somewhere else and it now works.

Comment: if you delete this question, you can pretend the whole thing never happened :)

Answer (score 0):

Your quotation marks are wrong.

the value of the `href` attribute should be surrounded by " marks. The value itself should contain only ' marks. Escape them properly (\') when necessary.